# Decoding Valgrind output

Tags: linux, valgrind

The output from valgrind with memory leak enabled is shown below.
From the stack trace, how do I find the location of the memory leak?
Could it be libpq.so?

```
==8909== 
==8909== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8909==     in use at exit: 373,468 bytes in 2,997 blocks
==8909==   total heap usage: 30,367 allocs, 27,370 frees, 5,535,985 bytes allocated
==8909== 
==8909== 123,640 (11,000 direct, 112,640 indirect) bytes in 55 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 290 of 291
==8909==    at 0x4C2B3F8: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8909==    by 0x52919F3: PQmakeEmptyPGresult (in /usr/lib/libpq.so.5.4)
==8909==    by 0x529BA40: ??? (in /usr/lib/libpq.so.5.4)
==8909==    by 0x5293767: PQgetResult (in /usr/lib/libpq.so.5.4)
==8909==    by 0x5293AB7: ??? (in /usr/lib/libpq.so.5.4)
==8909==    by 0x416B29: readTable() (thread.cpp:366)
==8909==    by 0x40D018: _ZNSt12_Bind_simpleIFPFvvEvEE9_M_invokeIIEEEvSt12_Index_tupleIIXspT_EEE (functional:1732)
==8909==    by 0x40CC94: std::_Bind_simple<void (*()())()>::operator()() (functional:1720)
==8909==    by 0x40CB55: std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*()())()> >::_M_run() (thread:115)
==8909==    by 0x5560ABF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17)
==8909==    by 0x65B9E99: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==8909==    by 0x5ABB3FC: clone (clone.S:112)
==8909== 
==8909== 123,640 (11,000 direct, 112,640 indirect) bytes in 55 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 291 of 291
==8909==    at 0x4C2B3F8: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8909==    by 0x52919F3: PQmakeEmptyPGresult (in /usr/lib/libpq.so.5.4)
==8909==    by 0x529BA40: ??? (in /usr/lib/libpq.so.5.4)
==8909==    by 0x5293767: PQgetResult (in /usr/lib/libpq.so.5.4)
==8909==    by 0x5293AB7: ??? (in /usr/lib/libpq.so.5.4)
==8909==    by 0x416E55: readTable() (thread.cpp:405)
==8909==    by 0x40D018: _ZNSt12_Bind_simpleIFPFvvEvEE9_M_invokeIIEEEvSt12_Index_tupleIIXspT_EEE (functional:1732)
==8909==    by 0x40CC94: std::_Bind_simple<void (*()())()>::operator()() (functional:1720)
==8909==    by 0x40CB55: std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*()())()> >::_M_run() (thread:115)
==8909==    by 0x5560ABF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17)
==8909==    by 0x65B9E99: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==8909==    by 0x5ABB3FC: clone (clone.S:112)
==8909== 
==8909== LEAK SUMMARY:
==8909==    definitely lost: 22,000 bytes in 110 blocks
==8909==    indirectly lost: 225,280 bytes in 110 blocks
==8909==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8909==    still reachable: 126,188 bytes in 2,777 blocks
==8909==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8909== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==8909== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
==8909== 
==8909== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==8909== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: No, not likely. It is likely `readTable` is using a resource from `libpq` and is not properly freeing it. Installing debug symbols for `libpq` may be helpful.

Comment: The leak summary says: definitely lost: 22,000 bytes in 110 blocks, so does this not mean that there is a memory leak?  If not then what would the Leak Summary contain if there was a memory leak?

Comment: I didn;t say there isn't a leak. I just said it's not the lib's fault. It is your fault, in the `readTable` function, which is NOT part of the lib.

Answer (score 0):

Try [attaching gdb to valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver-simple) and then setting a breakpoint to where you think the leak may be occurring.  Then, run `monitor leak_check` to see if anything has been lost.  As far as I know, you can't set a breakpoint for when you lose memory, but you can step through your program until you do.